# RDLC printing on half A4

Tags: .net, printing, report, reporting, rdlc

**What I want to accomplish**

Requirement: print a receipt which is of A4 width and half of A4 height and print it rotated so it can be printed on continuous A4 (CCP).

[image]

**What I always get**

[image]

**What I have tried**

RDLC report is defined as 205mm x 145mm so it should fit nicely in the available space.
I have tried the following

- print to A4 paper portrait
- print to A4 paper landscape
- create custom paper size defined as 210 x 147 and print portrait and landscape
- handle `PrintingBegin` event of the `ReportViewer` and set `DefaultPageSettings` to same paper size

Nothing helped. I seem to remember reading somewhere that if report height is smaller than width, printout is automatically rotated to landscape. I don't know if that feature can be turned off...

**Update:** Page size is 208mm x 147mm, margins are 12mm on all sides. Body of the report is 173mm x 121mm

Comment: have you set the margin to 0?

Comment: I tried giving an answer, but I guess it'd be better if you show us your code. That would really help. I appreciate your consideration!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, do you have answer for this question?

Comment: @Willy Sadly, no.

Comment: @Willy Actually, the answer from Smith might be the correct one. Try creating full height report, but leave bottom part empty. When printer driver detects empty space, it stops feeding the paper.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when printing on some time ago, I thought I should share the solution that worked for me. If you used an alternate route, you can also share, I would like to see what worked for you.

there is a trick, what you need to do is to create the report as a square i.e. Width = 210mm & Height = 210mm BUT only use the first 145mm of the report from top to bottom to place items.

leave the bottom 65mm space blank.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna give it a try.
My guess is you're using a set of libraries for printing which work well in the high level, but that you should use something more 'manual'.
My Dad owns a coffee shop and I made his POS software. Our receipt printer prints just the lines it takes with the code I'm going to give you. I'm guessing moving this way  could work for you.

This method does not print images, only text, that's important to know.

The printing methods in my code seem to be different from yours; they are "character-sensitive". This means, if you need 3 spacebar strokes worth of margins, you need to write 3 spacebar strokes and then your text.

To run this code, you'll have to create a '.txt' and then send that textfile as argument to the printing class.
I'm not sure if you're using c# or VB, my code's in c#.

So, first, to create a textfile at any point in your program you need the header:

```
using System.IO;
```

Then at the point it becomes necessary you'll start creating the textfile:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("receipt.txt");
```

This creates a file on your current folder -the same your .exe is located at. It will also overwrite old ones, so you don't need to worry if a file with the same name existed before.
To write your lines of the receipt you'll use:

```
sw.WriteLine("  the text is supposed to be written, you may use concatenations  ");
```

The WriteLine method writes a line of text into the file and then moves to the next line.

When you're done writing, you need to close the file with...

```
sw.Close();
```

You'll need then to call the printing class I'm gonne give you. Assuming you already have it, you'd need to create an instance of it as in:

```
PimpMyPrint p = new PimpMyPrint();
```

And then call the PrintDoc method with...

```
p.PrintDoc("receipt.txt");
```

Once again, you still need a class with all necessary methods.
I'M NOT GOING TO TAKE CREDIT FOR THIS CLASS; it is the work of author Francisco Javier Ceballos, from Spain. Mr Ceballos is a well-known author in Spanish-speaking SD community and this is from his book "Microsoft C# Curso de programación".

So here goes the class you need to add:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace SomeNamespace
{   
    class PimpMyPrint
    {
        private Font font;
        private StreamReader sr;

        public void PrintDoc(string textfile)
        {
            try
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(textfile);

                try
                {
                    font = new Font("Arial", 10);
                    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintPage);
                    pd.Print();
                }
                finally
                {
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private void PrintPage(object obj, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            float LinesPerPage = 0;
            float pos_Y = 0;
            int count = 0;
            float marginLeft = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
            float marginUP = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
            string line = null;

            float fontHeight = font.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);
            LinesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height / fontHeight;

            while (count < LinesPerPage && ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null))
            {
                pos_Y = marginUP + (count * fontHeight);
                ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, font, Brushes.Black, 0, pos_Y, new StringFormat());
                count++;
            }

            if (line != null)
                ev.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                ev.HasMorePages = false;
        }   
    }   
}
```

I hope this works for you as good as it has worked for me!